# Qt 5.11: UI element refreshed only when clicked

Tags: qt, qt5, macos-high-sierra, qtdeclarative, qt5.11

I have a project developed in an old version of Qt for Mac, maybe version 4. I have opened the project in the current version 5.11 for Mac. It seems that the `QtDeclarative` is no longer available. So, the only change I did was to remove this line from the project's `.pro` file.

```
QT += declarative
```

The project compiles and runs on macOS High Sierra. However, for the some UI elements, e.g. `QTableWidget` and `QTreeWidget`, I find that I need to click on the element for it to be refreshed after its content has been changed programmatically. This was not the case when the project was made in the previous version of Qt. Any help for this?

Comment: Try using widget->update(); after programmatically changing the contents.

Comment: Currently, I am using `widget->repaint()` to refresh. I can also force refresh all UI elements using `this->repaint()`